# Resize image width and scale height accordingly

Tags: php, image, gd, scale

I'm coding an uploading script, and I'm currently using a way of resizing images with gd which works good in general. The only issue is that when users upload portrait images, they align to center and the parts outside the canvas gets cut off. I've added a check to identify if the image is portait or not, but now I need to adjust some code to manipulate the portait images to the way I need them.

For instance, if I upload an image with a resolution of 2000x3000 pixels, I need the following to be done:

- Automaticly scale the width to 800px.
- Scale the height accordingly to the new width, keeping the original ratio.

I've managed to scale it, but it just keeps the original resolution, which is not the wanted effect. Maybe someone here could help me out?

Thanks in advance //
Jonathan

**EDIT: I managed to solve it by using my old technique, and just change the dimensions when the uploaded image orientation was portait. Thanks for your answers!**

Comment: This is a common problem with loads of easy-to-find solutions. What have you tried so far? Any libraries (PHP classes), 3rd party tools (e.g., imagick)?

Comment: By the way, I would not advise to check if an image is a portrait or a landscape. It works only if maximum height and maximum width of desirable result are the same. If they are different (e.g., image must fit in 800x600 px box), you should do a generic check - compare ratio of original width and height with ratio of desired width and height.

Comment: @binaryLV I am not using any libraries as of now, because I want to learn how to utilize GD in the best possible way before I do that. I'm now using a compilation of code I've attempted to perfect for what I need. The only missing key is now the portrait scaling.

Answer (score 0):

simple scaling function

```
function img_scale($source,$width,$height,$extra='border=0')
{
     $w=$width;
     $h=$height;
     $size = @getimagesize($abu_source); 
    if($w > $size[0] && $h > $size[1] )
    {
        $neww = $size[0];//$w;
        $newh = $size[1];//$h;
    }
    else if( $w < $size[0] && $h > $size[1] )
    {
        $diff=$size[0]-$w;
        $dec_per=(100*$diff)/$size[0];
        $neww=$size[0]-(($size[0]*$dec_per)/100);
        $newh=$size[1]-(($size[1]*$dec_per)/100);
    }
    else if( $w > $size[0] && $h < $size[1] )
    {
        $diff=$size[1]-$h;
        $dec_per=(100*$diff)/$size[1];
        $newh=$size[1]-(($size[1]*$dec_per)/100);
        $neww=$size[0]-(($size[0]*$dec_per)/100);
    }
    else//( $w < $size[0] && $h < $size[0] )
    {
        if( ($size[0]-$w) >= ($size[1]-$h))
        {
            $diff=$size[0]-$w;
            $dec_per=(100*$diff)/$size[0];
            $neww=$size[0]-(($size[0]*$dec_per)/100);
            $newh=$size[1]-(($size[1]*$dec_per)/100);
            $cc='w';
        }
        else
        {
            $diff=$size[1]-$h;
            $dec_per=(100*$diff)/$size[1];
            $newh=$size[1]-(($size[1]*$dec_per)/100);
            $neww=$size[0]-(($size[0]*$dec_per)/100);
            $cc='h';                    
        }
    }
    return "<img src='".$source."' width='".$neww."' height='".$newh."'  ".$extra." >";
}
```